# Date time selectors in padrino and Jquery using slim framework

Tags: jquery, sinatra, slim, padrino

I'm new in this tecs and i need to do a datetimepicker or something to choose a date vale.. is it any sort of "datetime_field"? or only is posible using Java sciprt or Jquery...
I tried something like this in my code.. but nothing heppends

```
= f.text_field :Eventdatetime, :class => 'form-control input-large input-with-feedback'
span class='help-inline' = error ? f.error_message_on(:Eventdatetime, :class => 'text-error') : pat(:example)
javascript:
   jQuery(function() {
    debugger;
    $( "#Eventdatetime" ).datepicker();
   });
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no method `datepicker()` in jQuery (you may be getting confused with its sister library jQuery UI) so you'll need to include an external library to implement such functionality.

I can recommend [this one](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/), I use it myself in production environments and have never had any issues with it. It's as easy to use as you'd expect:

```
$("input").datetimepicker();
new Date($("input").val());
```

Comment: Thanks will try this one now and let you know... thanks a lot